# Strange behaviour of PID in DLL used in child process?

Tags: .net, windows, dll, c++-cli, pid

I'm coding with C++/CLI, .net 4.5, VS2012, on Win7.

I have a main process **A.exe** that starts a second process **B.exe** using *System::Diagnostics::Process(::Start())*.

The second process **B.exe** uses a (native) DLL **C.dll**.

In **C.dll** I declared a static like this:

```
static bool B = true;
if(B == true )
{
    MyFile << "Switch true to false" << endl;
    B=false;
}
MyFile << _getpid() << endl;
```

What I get is that _getpid() returns the PID of **A.exe**, not the one of **B.exe**. I tough **C.dll** would be associated to process **B.exe**, not **A.exe**. ???????

Also, if I start **B.exe** several times (in a loop, say) in **A.exe**, the *static variable is never reset to true*. Why?

I don't know if it can help but I use:

```
StartProcessInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
StartProcessInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
```

The other fields keep their default values.

Can someone help me?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE 1**

Finally, both **A.exe** and **B.exe** load **C.dll**. But the question remains: shouldn't the static variables in the DLL be mapped twice, once for each executable???? And when I call the function that writes the PID, it is from **B.exe** because, during this time, **A.exe** waits for **B.exe** to complete.

Comment: Are you sure that you're seeing what you think you're seeing, can you examine the runtime behavior using Process Explorer?  Also, Process Explorer can show the loaded modules in both process, just recommending as an extra sanity check.

Comment: Like you, I was not sure! So I verified in ProcessExplorer and saw exactly what I said: **A.exe** is parent of **B.exe** and the PID returned by **C.dll** is **A.exe**'s PID!

Comment: Well, see UPDATE 1 in the question.

Comment: Are all processes writing to the same file?  If so, perhaps some instances are terminating early due to unhandled exceptions regarding file access.  That might explain the strange observations.